# Python updating list from constructor by object.attribute

Tags: python, list, constructor, append, mutable

If a class is created with the attributes: name and list and the name attribute has a default value and the list is appending the name. Is it possible in somehow when I create an object "a" and type
"a.name = 'x' " that this 'x' will appear in the list given that the list is appending in the **constructor**?

```
class Person:
    list = []
    def __init__(self, name="Zed"):
        self.name = name
        self.list.append(name)

    def printList(self):
        print(self.list)


a = Person()
a.name = "Yasuo"
a.printList() #outputs Zed but Yasuo is expected.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `name` a property, and implement a setter that updates the list.

```
class Person:
    list = []
    def __init__(self, name="Zed"):
        self._name = name
        self.list.append(name)
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name
    @name.setter
    def name(self, name):
        if self._name in self.list:
            # remove the old name
            index = self.list.index(self.name)
            self.list[index] = name
        else:
            self.list.append(name)
        self._name = name
    def printList(self):
        print(self.list)

a = Person()
a.name = "Yasuo"
a.printList() # prints ['Yasuo']
```

Comment: I agree with you but I dont know why they want us to do it the append under the __init__(), I think that is stupid. And they also want the "Zed" to be overwritten when we do "a.name" so that in this case a.printList() prints Yasuo without Zed in the list.

Comment: I tried to put the list on the body under the class, but it still did not work... Does it have to do with that the list is a default mutable attribute in this case and that it should be implemented in different way? I think it is very confusing...

Comment: Why is it a list if they want to replace instead of append?

Comment: I've changed the answer to replace `self.list[0]` with the new name.

Comment: Are you sure `list` is supposed to be an instance attribute rather than a class attribute? Maybe they want a list of all the instances, or a list of the names of all the people?

Comment: Im very sorry! You are right, list should be a class attribute!  Will that mean that I dont need property and setter? Or what is the difference in the implementation when list is a class attribute?

Comment: You still need a setter if you want anything extra to happen when assigning to `name`.

Comment: I see! so it should not be possible to append "Yasuo" from the constructor directly given that the list is a class attribute right?

Comment: I've updated the answer. You can access class attributes from the constructor, since they're created when the class is defined.

Comment: However, I couldn't use `self.name = name` in the constructor, because now the setter needs to access the old name so it can replace it, but the old name hasn't been set yet.

Comment: I discovered one weird thing. When I type self.list.append(name +"something") the output is "zed something, Yasuo" but expected output in this case: Yasuo something

Comment: Sure. It only replaces `Zed` with `Yasuo`. If you have other names in the list, they're left alone.

Comment: It won't replace `Zed` if it's just part of someone else's name.

Comment: I understand! I replaced within the setter "if self._name + "something" in self.list" and then I did "index = self.list.index(self.name + "something").  It worked but im not sure if this is the best approach

Comment: Why do you need to add `something`?

Comment: Nvm I got it wrong. But If I for example want to append to the list something like "Yasuo is my name" would you recommend me to edit the setter?

Comment: Why do that in the list, do that in the method that prints the names.

Comment: I 100% agree with you! I dont know WHY we were given that requirement

Comment: Whatever you do when saving the string in the list, you also have to do when checking if it's already in the list.